# How do I get back to shooting mode with the D5100?

Tags: nikon-d5100, camera-controls

Yesterday I got my Nikon D5100. After initial setup, I clicked a picture. All okay. Then to learn, I pressed the 'i' button to view the settings. Now I am not able to come out of this information display on my screen. To take a photo I have to see through the viewfinder. I can't see that on my screen/monitor. I can still take pictures and review them. How do I bring back my screen to see the shooting mode?

Comment: That may sound stupid, but did you check the manual? Just googling it, it says there's a switch to go from viewfinder mode to live view mode. Also, usually, if you press the same button that you originally pressed, it would "cancel" the effect. At least on most UIs I know of...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to press the button again to come out of the info display (or it may take two presses). On my D700, pressing the shutter button part way turns the LCD off.

However, if you want to view the "to be taken" photo from the LCD, you want to press the button for Live View (check your owner's manual, as the D700 doesn't have this - my old D90 did -probably labelled "LV") and that will display what you are point at, like a P&S camera.

You'll want to read up on Live View, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

On page 44 on http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5100_EN.pdf it says the live view switch can be moved towards the rear of the camera to engage the live view mode. The live view mode will lift the mirror allowing you to frame your shot using the lcd. However, because the mirror is raised you will probably not be able to use the viewfinder while in live view.

Hope this helps.

*I do not own any Nikon camera all my advise comes from a quick look at the manual from the provided link*

Comment: There's also the [Nikon Digitutor](http://www.nikondigitutor.com/eng/d5100/index.html) for those that hate reading manuals :) I do own a D5100, and can confirm: Press the 'i' button to toggle the info display on and off, press the 'Lv' lever towards you to toggle Live view. Just note that the viewfinder autofocus works better than the live view autofocus in low light, so you may want to switch to the viewfinder (turning off the live view) if you have trouble focusing.

Answer (score 0):

If the USB cable is attached between the camera & PC, the live view LV lever doesn't engage.  Ensure the cable isn't attached to your PC.